# Como poner un hipervínculo en xml?

Tags: css, xml

Quiero poner un hipervínculo en un documento XML si usar etiquetas 
ni xsl solo con CSS ¿ Seria posible ?

Comment: Te sugiero que lo intentes. Si obtienes algún error o el resultado no es el esperado, pregunta aquí las veces que necesites, agregando necesariamente un __[mcve]__ que ilustre dicho problema o error.

Comment: se puede poner un hipervinculo en xml como una propiedad del nodo
Pero no estoy muy seguro que con css se le permita crear elhipervinculo como tal, Suerte

Comment: Pero yo lo que quiero es que funcione el link en el navegador

Comment: puedes hacerlo con un xslt, te quedara de maravilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunos lenguajes de XML tienen sus proprios elementos para hipervínculos, XHTML tiene el elemento `<a href="http://example.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">ejemplo</a>`, SVG tiene `<a xlink:href="http://example.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">...</a>` tomado de XLinks. Sin embargo, hoy en día se puede considerar XLink en general muerto despues de que Mozilla quitara la implementación de Gecko. Sin embargo, utilizar un elemento `a` de XHTML en tu documento de XML debería funcionar, incluso si los otros elementos no pertenecen a XHTML.

Acabo de escribir el ejemplo https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017060904.xml que utiliza https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017060904.css, el documento XML es

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="test2017060904.css"?>
<documento xml:lang="es">
    <división>
        <título>Esto es un test</título>
        <párrafo>Esto es un test: ¿Funciona este <a href="http://example.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">enlace</a>?</párrafo>
    </división>
</documento>
```

CSS es

```
documento, división, título, párrafo {
    display: block;
}

título {
    font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold;
}
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

en los cuatro navegadores que tengo (IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox) el enlace funciona.

Answer (score 0):

una forma muy facil de hacerlo es usando **`xsl`** no tendras problemas por que es un standard de la **W3C** el unico *"incoveniente"* es que debe estar publicada para Chrome ya que te dara un error de seguridad al no permitir abrir el fichero xsl;
aqui un ejemplo:

**titulos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="titulos.xsl"?> 
<documento>
    <division>
        <titulo>mi titulo 1</titulo>
        <parrafo>mi parrafo 1</parrafo>
        <enlace>http://example.com/</enlace>
    </division>
        <division>
        <titulo>mi titulo 2</titulo>
        <parrafo>mi parrafo 2</parrafo>
        <enlace>http://example.com/</enlace>
    </division>
</documento>
```

como podras observar en la cabecera de titulos.xml defino el xsl a utilizar

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="titulos.xsl"?>
```

**titulos.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Ejemplo</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>titulo</th>
        <th>Parrafo</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="documento/division">
      <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="enlace" select="enlace"/>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="titulo"/></td>
        <td><a href="{$enlace}"><xsl:value-of select="parrafo"/></a></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```